# Delayed execution when using @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

I have been facing a problem when i put **@Transactional** annotation on a method.
Sometime before starting the method, it got delayed start for 15 minutes (928787 millisecond in my log) and then complete the execution in a few millisecond.

It's not always reproduced. I found this problem 1 in 100000 of the method executions.

It seems something went wrong in the proxy when TaskDispatcher trying to invoke save() method.

**TaskDispatcher.java**

```
public class TaskDispatcher extends Thread {
    private DBProcessor dbProcessor;
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor;
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.myTaskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dbProcessor.processData(data);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**DBProcessor.java**

```
public class DBProcessor extends ADataProcessor {
    private DBService dbService;
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean processData(Data data) throws DataProcessorException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        success = dbService.save(tradeReportID, translatedMessages, result);

        logger.info("processing time : {} ms.", tradeReportID, action, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        return success;
    }

}
```

**DBServiceImpl.java**

```
public class DBServiceImpl extends CustomRepository implements DBService {
    ...
    @Transactional
    public boolean save(String tradeOrderId, List<TranslatedMessage> translatedMessages, DBDealServiceResult result) throws DealProcessorException, DealProcessorExceptionNoRollback {
        logger.info("start DB processing");

        ... // do some db operation

        logger.info("finished DB processing");
        return success;
    }
}
```

**spring.xml**

```
...
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="connectionPoolDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.myapp.jpa.entity" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">  
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="${hibernate.generate_statistics}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" /> 
</bean>
```

**Logs show the timing of executions**

```
2018/05/17 01:58:36.903|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-4] c.m.m.a.d.DBServiceImpl start DB processing
2018/05/17 01:58:36.915|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-4] c.m.m.a.p.DBServiceImpl finished DB processing
2018/05/17 01:58:36.920|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-4] c.m.m.a.d.DBProcessor processing time : 17 ms.
2018/05/17 01:58:36.931|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-16] c.m.m.a.d.DBServiceImpl start DB processing
2018/05/17 01:58:37.745|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-16] c.m.m.a.p.DBServiceImpl finished DB processing
2018/05/17 01:58:37.745|INFO |[myTaskExecutor-16] c.m.m.a.d.DBProcessor processing time : 928787 ms.
```

**Version Details :**

```
spring-framework : 5.0.5.RELEASE
spring-tx : 5.0.5.RELEASE
spring-jdbc : 5.0.5.RELEASE
spring-orm : 5.0.5.RELEASE
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api : 1.0.0.Final
hibernate-core : 5.2.7.Final
tomcat-jdbc : 7.0.70
oracle driver : ojdbc7 12.1.0.2
```

Comment: Is it possible the connection pool is overused and the time is going to waiting for a connection? Although there should be sensible default timeouts for waiting for a connection from the pool.

Comment: Thank you @Kayaman, I have another thread to monitor the idle/active connection. It show me that the number of active connection doesn't reach 50% of max connections. So, i don't think the connection pool is overused.